# How to use Javascript to keep a running score on multiple choice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to work this one out for ages, but just can't seem to wrap my brain around it.

Here's my HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="-5">Answer 1</option>
    <option value="5">Answer 2</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="-5">Answer 1</option>
    <option value="5">Answer 2</option>
</select>

<p class="total">0</p>
```

And here's my JS:

```
var score = 0;
var scoreNew = 0;
$('select').change(function() {
    scoreNew = parseInt($(this).val()) + parseInt(score);
    $('.total').text(scoreNew);
})
```

What happens:

- If you select Answer 1, the score is -5
- If you select Answer 2, the score is 5 (so far so good)
- But if you then go to Q2 and select Ans1, the score goes to -5 (whereas it should now be 0)

I thought I fixed it with the following code (but I didn't):

```
var score = 0;
var scoreNew = 0;
$('select').change(function() {
    scoreNew += Number($(this).val());
    $('.total').text(scoreNew);
})
```

What happens now:

- If I select Ans1, I get -5 (so far so good)
- But if I then select Ans2, I get 0 (where it should be 5)

I feel like I almost need a combination of those 2 methods, but can't quite figure it out.

I hope that all makes sense. If anyone can help it would be hugely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The simplest way is probably within the change handler to loop through *all* selects and (re)calculate the full total from scratch. That way if the user repeatedly changes the answer for the same select you don't need to worry about subtracting that answer's previous score.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I ideally need the score to update with each answer change, as opposed to showing the score via a button at the end. Is there any way you can elaborate on implementing a "mechanism to remove the previous answer's value"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've declared `total` outside the scope of your change handler, it will retain its last assigned value and therefore any further changes will be applied to the updated total rather than the original one of 0.

If you need to update on each select, you should declare the variable locally and recalculate using all the current values of your select elements:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $('select').each(function() {
    total += Number($(this).val());
  });
  $('.total').text(total);
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zgj6sq05/

Comment: Yes! This works absolutely perfectly! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem

```
var score = 0;
var scoreNew = 0;
$('select').change(function() {
    scoreNew = parseInt($(this).val()) + parseInt(score); //score is always 0
    $('.total').text(scoreNew);
})
```

You add the new score to 0. Change that line to

```
scoreNew += parseInt($(this).val());
```

and get rid of the `score` var. Not sure why it's there?

**Edit:**

Updated method

```
$('select').change(function() {
  var score = 0
  // run through each value and rebuild score
  $('select').each(function(){
    score += parseInt($(this).val())
  })
  $('.total').text(score);
})
```

It rebuilds the score on every change. Seems lame but it's quite fast.

I'm hoping this is a "test" project since nothing here is production level.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48xed3sh/) if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Tacking a fiddle onto your answer since I had it made. https://jsfiddle.net/L609usy3/

Comment: This solution was in my original question (see my 2nd method) and doesn't work as I need. For the first question, if you select Answer 1, your score should be -5, and if you select Answer 2, your score should be 5.
But what actually happens with this method, is you choose Answer 1 to give you -5, and then Answer 2 will give you 0 (not +5).