# Assign and count score, stay selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, multipleselection

I'm looking for a similar solutions to his but without select/option because I can't have a dropdown!
[How to use Javascript to keep a running score on multiple choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083175/how-to-use-javascript-to-keep-a-running-score-on-multiple-choice)
So I have multiple divs on the page and I need to assign scores to them and count the overall scores by the elements selected on the page. I hope someone can help - would be very much appreciated!

The elements that should be counted display in sliders, so it looks something like this:

select your score

```
                <div class="slider-test-1">

                <div class="slider-test">
                    <div class="slider-score">
                    <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">1</h2></div>
                    <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">2</h2></div>
                    <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">3</h2></div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="test-text">Description
                    </p>
                </div>
                        
                    <div class="slider-test">
                        <div class="slider-score">
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">4</h2></div>
                            <div class="slider-score-section"><h2 class="heading-t2">5</h2></div>
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">6</h2></div>
                            </div>
                        <p class="test-text">Description
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="slider-test">
                        <div class="slider-score">
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">7</h2></div>
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">8</h2></div>
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">9</h2></div>
                            </div>
                        <p class="test-text">Description
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="slider-test">
                        <div class="slider-score">
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">10</h2></div>
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">11</h2></div>
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">12</h2></div>
                            </div>
                        <p class="test-text">Description
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

```
                <div class="slider-test">
                    <div class="slider-score">
                    <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">1</h2></div>
                    <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">2</h2></div>
                    <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">3</h2></div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="test-text">Description
                    </p>
                </div>
                        
                    <div class="slider-test">
                        <div class="slider-score">
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">4</h2></div>
                            <div class="slider-score-section"><h2 class="heading-t2">5</h2></div>
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">6</h2></div>
                            </div>
                        <p class="test-text">Description
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="slider-test">
                        <div class="slider-score">
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">7</h2></div>
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">8</h2></div>
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">9</h2></div>
                            </div>
                        <p class="test-text">Description
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="slider-test">
                        <div class="slider-score">
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">10</h2></div>
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">11</h2></div>
                            <div class="slider-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">12</h2></div>
                            </div>
                        <p class="test-text">Description
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="total">0</div>
```

The score value is 1-12 like stated in the headers for each slider and the total score should be the score obtained on each slider (so for example 6 for slider 1 + 8 for slider 2 = 14 in total).
Thank you in advance if you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const totalDiv = document.querySelector('.total')

const sliderScores = [0, 0]

function updateTotal() {
  totalDiv.textContent = sliderScores[0] + sliderScores[1]
}

document.querySelectorAll('.slider-1-score-section').forEach(scoreSection => {
  scoreSection.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    sliderScores[0] = parseInt(event.target.textContent, 10)
    updateTotal()
  })
})

document.querySelectorAll('.slider-2-score-section').forEach(scoreSection => {
  scoreSection.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    sliderScores[1] = parseInt(event.target.textContent, 10)
    updateTotal()
  })
})
```

```css
.slider-1-score-section{
background-color: #cdb0b0;
}

.slider-2-score-section{
background-color: #bce0ba;
}
```

```html
<div class="total">0</div>

<div class="slider-test-1">
  <div class="slider-test">
    <div class="slider-score">
      <div class="slider-1-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">1</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-1-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">2</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-1-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">3</h2></div>
    </div>
    <p class="test-text">Description
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-test">
    <div class="slider-score">
      <div class="slider-1-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">4</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-1-score-section"><h2 class="heading-t2">5</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-1-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">6</h2></div>
    </div>
    <p class="test-text">Description
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-test">
    <div class="slider-score">
      <div class="slider-1-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">7</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-1-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">8</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-1-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">9</h2></div>
    </div>
    <p class="test-text">Description
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-test">
    <div class="slider-score">
      <div class="slider-1-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">10</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-1-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">11</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-1-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">12</h2></div>
    </div>
    <p class="test-text">Description
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider-test-1">
  <div class="slider-test">
    <div class="slider-score">
      <div class="slider-2-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">1</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-2-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">2</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-2-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">3</h2></div>
    </div>
    <p class="test-text">Description
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-test">
    <div class="slider-score">
      <div class="slider-2-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">4</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-2-score-section"><h2 class="heading-t2">5</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-2-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">6</h2></div>
    </div>
    <p class="test-text">Description
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-test">
    <div class="slider-score">
      <div class="slider-2-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">7</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-2-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">8</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-2-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">9</h2></div>
    </div>
    <p class="test-text">Description
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-test">
    <div class="slider-score">
      <div class="slider-2-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">10</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-2-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">11</h2></div>
      <div class="slider-2-score-section" ><h2 class="heading-t2">12</h2></div>
    </div>
    <p class="test-text">Description
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alright, you could use an array (here `sliderScores`) to keep track of the selected score for each slider. If the slider score updates on click you can add a click event handler to update the proper array item and the overall total score.

Note that you have to differentiate the sliders somehow in order to know which array item to update, here I've assigned a different class (`slider-1-score-section` and `slider-2-score-section`).

Comment: Thank you so much Stefan, this works great!! What I'm still trying to add is a function that changes the appearence of the selected score. My problem is that I don't know how to allow only one selection per slide.. Could you please advise? Here's the fiddle: https://codepen.io/rebekaranna/pen/gOrXzdp

Comment: You need to use document.getElementsByClassName('slider-1-score-section') instead of document.getElementsByTagName('slider-1-score-section').